# Creating a amortization schedule in pyspark using values from the previous row and current rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe which has all the payment dates for a particular account. as well as the first record containing the ending balance after the first payment was made which is the amount remaining on a loan.

| account | date | payment_number | start_balance | weekly_payment | interest_rate | interest_amount | principal_amount | ending_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 20000 | 250 | 0.02 | 15.45 | 234.55 | 19,765.45 |
| 1 | 2021-01-07 | 2 |  | 250 | 0.02 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2021-01-14 | 3 |  | 250 | 0.02 |  |  |  |

Here is the starting sample dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateDataFrameExample").getOrCreate()

# Create a list of tuples with the data
data = [
    (1, "2021-01-01", 1, 2000, 250, 0.02, 15.45, 234.55, 19765.45),
    (1, "2021-01-07", 2, None, 250, 0.02, None, None, None),
    (1, "2021-01-14", 3, None, 250, 0.02, None, None, None)
]

# Create a PySpark DataFrame from the list of tuples
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["account", "date", "payment_number", "start_balance", "weekly_payment",
                                  "interest_rate", "interest_amount", "principal_amount", "ending_balance"])
```

I want to perform the calculations in pyspark row by row so the start_balance, principal_amount and ending_balance columns are updated:

| account | date | payment_number | start_balance | weekly_payment | interest_rate | interest_amount | principal_amount | ending_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 20000 | 250 | 0.02 | 15.45 | 234.55 | 19,765.45 |
| 1 | 2021-01-07 | 2 | 19,765.45 | 250 | 0.02 | 15.20 | 234.8 | 19,530.65 |
| 1 | 2021-01-14 | 3 | 19,530.65 | 250 | 0.02 | 15.00 | 235 | 19,295.65 |

**Formulas:**

1. start_balance = last record ending balance
2. interest_amount =  start_balance *(current date - last date) *(interest_rate/365)
3. principal_amount = weekly_payment - interest_amount
4. ending_balance = start_balance - principal_amount

My first thought is to use the lag function to get the ending_balance from the previous row, the problem is there is a dependency on calculating the "ending_balance" which requires the values from the current row.

```
  # get the ending balance from the previous row
  #df = df.filter(df.payment_number.isin([1,2,3,4]))
  window_spec = Window.partitionBy("lse_nbr").orderBy("payment_number")
  prev_ending_balance =  lag('ending_balance', 1).over(window_spec)
  prev_schedule_date = lag('date',1).over(window_spec)
  # calculate the new values for the current row
  beginning_balance = when(col("payment_number") == 1, col('beginning_balance')).when(col("payment_number") > 1, prev_ending_balance)
  interest = when(col("payment_number") == 1,col("interest"))\
      .when(col("payment_number") > 1,round(beginning_balance * ((col("interest_rate")/100)/365) * datediff(col("date"),prev_schedule_date),2))
  principal_payment =  when(col("payment_number") == 1,col('principal_payment')).when(col("payment_number") > 1, round(col('customer_payment') - interest,2 ))
  ending_balance = when(col("payment_number") == 1,col("ending_balance")).otherwise(round(start_balance - principal_payment,2))
  payment_schedule_calculated_df = df.withColumn('ending_balance', ending_balance)\
            .withColumn('principal_amount', principal_amount)\
            .withColumn('interest', interest)\
            .withColumn('start_balance', start_balance)\
  
  return payment_schedule_calculated_df
```

I can solve this iterating row by row using df.collect() but my dataset is very large (100,000,000 records and this approach does not scale since all the records go to the driver.

is there any way to solve this using pyspark methods?

Comment: it's not cleat how the value are updated, it's better to share a formula something like column1 = previous column1 + column2 ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the formulas

Comment: I'm not sure you formulas are right, for interest_amount and ending_balance can you recheck please ?

Comment: Thanks for that catch. I made some updates